# Как использовать новые функции android 4+ если минимальная рабочая версия должна быть 2.2

Tags: java, android, совместимость

Разрабатываю приложение и хочется чтобы работало начиная с версии android 2.2, но для пользователей телефонов с версией 4+ хотелось бы использовать новые функции. Подскажите как можно выполнить такое условие в одном приложении?

Comment: нужно добавлять условие, которое будет проверять текущю версию sdk (то есть, версию андроида, где запущенно приложение). И выполнять нужный код. [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093369/check-sdk-version-and-if)

Comment: Но ведь api не совпадает. Какой версии тогда sdk использовать для проекта? Если минимальную, то классы из новых версий будут не доступны и компиляция не пройдет, а если максимально доступной версии, то не скомпилируется код, если использовать старый api.

Comment: Можно ли как-то выпускать несколько версий, но пользователю будет видна только одна? Правда не понятно какую версию показывать если пользователь зашел в google play через браузер на настольном pc

Comment: Нашел на сайте android http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html но есть ли возможность обойтись одним apk или только несколькими?

Comment: О каких функциях речь?

Comment: @lukdiman указывайте минимальную версию 2.2, а targetSDK - 4.4 и все будет нормально.

Comment: Да указать-то можно и минимальную и target, но при компиляции полюбому будет только одна версия. Соответственно будет ошибка компиляции, т.к. api у версий разные. Допустим мне нужен Fragment. Если я буду компилировать с 2.2 то будет ошибка компиляции. Тоже самое может быть обратно. Допустим класс будет в 2.2 но не будет в 4.4 или сигнатура какого-то метода будет не соответствовать и тоже будет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: для обратной совместимости придумали Android Support Library. Эта библиотека привнесла Фрагменты аж в API v4...
Вообще, большинство методов сохраняют сигнатуру для совместимости.    
Как написали выше, выставляйте в targetSDK самую что ни на есть последнюю, а в minSDK - минимум (рекомендую ставить 10, т. к. дивайсов на СДК < 10 осталось меньше 1.5%)

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 способа решения данной проблемы:

1) По рецепту [[@metalurgus](/users/3997/metalurgus)](/users/3997/metalurgus) - через Android Support Library. Но увы не все функции 4-го будут доступны при использовании такого способа

2) Ветвиться через `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` и вытаскивать нужные методы через рефлексию.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 ) {//Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    final String className="android.print.PrintManager";
    Class clazz=null;
    try {
        clazz=Class.forName(className);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Class not found", e);
        return;
    }
    Method[] mt=clazz.getMethods(); //получаем список методов класса
    //blah-blah
    //далее уже можно вызвать нужный метод через Method.invoke();
}
```

Comment: Второй вариант выглядит конечно жутко костыльно :) Но буду иметь ввиду оба варианта.